# Python - mechanize - mechanize does not recognize a form

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

I m using `mechanize` to fill a form on [this website](http://www.nimes-metropole.fr/lagglo/deliberations.html), however it does not recognize the form I want to fill (the "Délibérations" form). Here is the code I am using:

```
link = 'http://www.nimes-metropole.fr/lagglo/deliberations.html' 
browser.open(link)
for form in browser.forms():
   print form
```

and I get:

```
<get http://www.nimes-metropole.fr/pages-speciales/recherche.html application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(id=262) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(L=0) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(tx_solr[q]=)>
  <SubmitControl(<None>=Valider) (readonly)>>
```

This form is not the one I want. Do you have any idea why it only recognizes this form?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at the source of the page shows that is the only html form present. The other form is in an iframe sourced from https://extranet01.nimes.fr/deliberations/index.php?origin=2

Comment: Thank you! The code works with link ="https://extranet01.nimes.fr/deliberations/index.php?origin=2"